# Bootstrap Accordion border top not first item

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

I'm using bootstraps accordions in a Angular application and I would like to have a border with color at everyone al around. By standard bootstrap removes the top border if the accordion not the top one.
I have tried everything I can figure out.

What I can se it is

```
.accordion-item:not(:first-of-type) {
    border-top: 0;`
```

that removes the top border.

I have tried:

```
.accordion-item:{
    border-top:4px !important;
}
```

```
.accordion-item:{
    &:not(:first-of-type) {
        border-top: 4px !important;
    }
}
```

the last one results in this computed at that element:
[accordion not having top border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Viv4e.png)

I have tried to add margins between the accordions, It don't help

I cant find what's overwriting it.
Anyone know?

EDIT:
Adding solid solved the problem but gave me a new one:
I render the border color dynamically depending on a variable i the accordion.
I get i like this:

```
    <div
      *ngFor="let finding of findings"
      class="accordion-item"
      [ngStyle]="{
        'border-color': finding.level.color,
        'border-top-color': finding.level.color
      }"
    >
```

But the top border on the accordions that are not first is always black (se picture)
[image: top border black color]

This is how the css file looks

```
.accordion-item{
    border-width: 4px !important;

    &:not(:first-of-type) {
        border-top: 4px solid !important;
      }
}
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz and screenshot of expected output?

Comment: _"I cant find what's overwriting it"_ - the _effective_ border-top-width is shown as `0px`, despite the 4px you have specified, because of what the _previous_ line of your screenshot there shows - `border-top-style: none`. A border with no border _style_, can not _have_ a width either.

Comment: Thanks! Adding solid helped. 
However now I got a new problem.. 
I get the border-color from a variable set like this:

```[ngStyle]="{'border-color': finding.level.color, 'border-top-color': finding.level.color}"
``` \n
But the top-border i always black. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.accordion-item:not(:first-of-type) {
    border-top: 4px solid blue;
}
```

When dealing with styles in Angular applications, it's important to consider the component based nature of angular and how styles are encapsulated within components.

Try and do let me know how it works.

Comment: Thanks! Adding solid helped. 
However now I got a new problem.. 
I get the border-color from a variable set like this:

```[ngStyle]="{'border-color': finding.level.color, 'border-top-color': finding.level.color}"
``` \n
But the top-border i always black. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Okay as far as I understood, try this : <div
  *ngFor="let finding of findings; let i = index"
  class="accordion-item"
  [ngStyle]="{'border-color': i === 0 ? finding.level.color : 'transparent'}"
> and for CSS make changes like this :  .accordion-item {
  border-width: 4px !important;
  border-style: solid !important;
}

.accordion-item:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-top: 4px solid !important;
}

Comment: nopp, that only made the other borders transparent, the top border was still black.
However, I added `style="border: 4px solid"` to the element and that solved the problem

Comment: Ah, great to know that.